# Not able to insert index into ElasticSearch DB container on AKS

Tags: elasticsearch, azure-aks, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have installed Elasticsearch and Kibana as containers in AKS. Following is how the services are looking like:
[image]

I am able to see that both the services are up and running by hitting the external IP addresses. But the problem is I am not sure if Kibana is able to get connected to Elasticsearch or not. How do I check that? Because when I do not get a successful response if I hit the below url:
[image]

I am using the below code to get the logs from my Azure LogAnalytics workspace and insert into ElasticSearch DB:

```
private static void UploadLogToElasticSearchDB(Microsoft.Azure.OperationalInsights.Models.Table dt)
        {
            ElasticClient client = null;
            var uri = new Uri("http://13.87.227.42:9200/");
            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri);
            client = new ElasticClient(settings);
            settings.DefaultIndex("k8scontainercpu");

            for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var dtRowJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt.Rows[i]);
                client.IndexAsync<string>(dtRowJSON, null);
            }
        }
```

This program is running infinitely and not inserting any records, it is not giving any errors also, I do not see anything unusual in the Output window of the program. How to insert indexes in the elasticsearch DB of AKS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you able to connect using external IP and port, then the service is working correctly. Outside the cluster internal service name won't be accessible.

You can open the kibana external url and check if kibana is able to connect to elastic search or not. if kibana is not able to connect to elastic search it would be visible in the health status of kibana. However if you are able to connect to elastic search externally, kibana should be able to connect with it easily.

Regarding, index creation, you can use kibana to create index also. See [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.8/connect-to-elasticsearch.html) on how to create index using kibana.
ES also has api to create index [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html)

To troubleshoot what documents are not getting inserting into ES, I would suggest to use Index function (which is a sync function) and track the response of the call so thay you can identify what is happening in the call. You can read about it from [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/indexing-documents.html)